# Plotting issue -- possible bug?

Tags: plotting, graphics

**Issue:** a plot that previously worked in version 10.1 (see first figure below) produced an odd looking graph when re-evaluated in version 10.2 (see second graph).  I have downloaded the latest version, (10.3) but the issue persists. I am working on a Mac.

**Picture of graph from before:**

[image: before]

**Same graph now looks like this:**

[image: after]

Any suggestions on what might be the issue?

I have also tried changing the `Antialiasing` setting (See: Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics), but that did not help resolve the issue.

**Code:**
The code below is similar to that used to generate the graph above. I just removed some non-essential elements of the code so that it would be faster/easier to reproduce.  This code still yields the same issue; the only difference is that the resulting function looks more like a step-function now.

```
z = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[2, 2], 100];

f[x_, y_] := 
 Sum[(
    Boole[(z[[i]] - (Min[z[[i]], x]) - y) > Max[z[[i]] - x, 0]] + 
    Boole[(z[[i]] - x) > Max[(z[[i]] - (Min[z[[i]], x]) - y), 0]]),
   {i, 1, 100}
 ];

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

Comment: I have no idea. Can you post how you generated the plot?

Comment: Using your code, I was able to reproduce the issue with V10.3 running on OS X.

Comment: What if you add `Exclusions -> None`?

Comment: Replicated on 10.3 on Linux (Mint 17.2 xfce x64).

Comment: @J.M. using the "Exclusions -> None" option does appear to fix the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That would be on account of the `Boole[]`, `Max[]`, and `Min[]` parts. Sometimes, *Mathematica* tries to be too clever in excluding jump discontinuities that it ends up not plotting much of the function. I believe a question like this has been asked before, but I cannot find it.

Comment: I have tried this on versions 8, 9, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3 and in all cases I get the same result (apart from the effects of PlotTheme, as this option didn't exist before 10). I could NOT reproduce the result you claim came from version 10.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not see a difference between the versions you reported, at least not for the function you use in your question. The result I get for 10.1 is the same as 10.3 and all other versions I tried (8, 9, 10.0, 10.2).

The main problem is that your function has discrete steps at highly irregular positions. `Plot3D` is not really suiuted for these types of functions, but you can improve your result by increasing the `PlotPoints` option value:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`DiscretePlot3D` may be better suited for plots like this one:

```
DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1, 1/60}, {y, 0, 1, 1/60}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ExtentSize -> Full, Filling -> None, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This was with a regular grid. In the case of this function, function state is particular dependent on the relation between x and y and the values of z (all of which lie between 0 and 1). Making use of this, lets sample x and y using the z list itself:

```
DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y], {x, Union[z ]}, {y, Union[z]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ExtentSize -> Full, Filling -> None, 
 Joined -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]